# How to put constraints on Prolog facts?

Tags: prolog

This are facts:

```
address(host1, '10.0.0.1').
address(host2, '10.0.0.2').
```

And I can query a fact:

```
?- address(host1, X).
X = '10.0.0.1'.
```

I am new to Prolog but I am used to relational databases.  In a SQL database I put constrains on the data to prevent errors. If I want to ensure, that all addresses are in the class A network 10.0.0.0/8, I can put a constrain on the table column:

```
create table hosts (
  name    text,
  address text check (address like '10.%')
);
```

How would I do the same in Prolog to prevent wrong facts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **facts** you have written are equivalent to the following **rules**:

```
address(host1, '10.0.0.1') :- true.
address(host2, '10.0.0.2') :- true.
```

`true/0` is the **most general goal**: It *always succeeds*.

To **constrain** the clauses more strongly, you can add further goals. In Prolog, each goal acts as a **constraint** on answers.

@coder's answer is spot on: You can simply write rules to add these checks, and they are similar to (and more expressive than) your database constraints.

For example, you can write:

```
host_ip(host1, IP) :- IP = '10.0.0.1', good_ip(IP).
host_ip(host2, IP) :- IP = '10.0.0.2', good_ip(IP).
```

Note the predicate naming convention: To make clear what each argument is, I am using `host_ip/2` instead of simply `address/2`.

A possible definition of `good_ip/1` would be:

```
good_ip(IP) :- atom_concat('10.', _, IP).
```

This is true **iff** `IP` starts with `10.` .

At this point, the question arises whether you have chosen the most suitable **representation** of IP addresses!

If you frequently need to analyze components, consider for example the representation:

> **`ip(A,B,C,D)`**

In this representation, we could write:

```
host_ip(host1, IP) :- IP = ip(10,0,0,1), good_ip(IP).
host_ip(host2, IP) :- IP = ip(10,0,0,2), good_ip(IP).

good_ip(ip(10,_,_,_)).
```

---

**EDIT**: As you correctly point out in the comments, this only prevents **fetching** wrong IPs, not **asserting** or **adding** wrong facts or clauses.

To make the latter possible, consider the approach outlined by @lurker: You can simply define a rule like:

```
add_host_ip(Host, IP) :-
    good_ip(IP),
    assertz(host_ip(Host,IP)).
```

This prevents you from **adding** wrong IPs to the database, assuming you consistently use this interface predicate.

Note also that you combine this with throwing an **exception** if a wrong IP is given. For example:

```
good_ip(ip(First,_,_,_)) :-
    dif(First, 10),
    throw(wrong_subnet(First)).
good_ip(ip(10,_,_,_)).
```

Example session:

```
?- add_host_ip(host3, ip(11,0,0,0)).
ERROR: Unhandled exception: wrong_subnet(11)

?- add_host_ip(host4, ip(10,0,0,1)).
true.

?- host_ip(host3, IP).
false.

?- host_ip(host4, IP).
IP = ip(10, 0, 0, 1).
```

This illustrates that invalid IPs are now neither stored nor returned as answers.

Comment: But in your example it is still possible to define an invalid address `host´_ip(host3, IP) :- IP = ip(1,2,3,4), good_ip(IP).` The effect is just, that it can not be found anymore. But the facts database is still corrupt, because although an address for `host3` has been defined it is missing.

Comment: That's right; I have added code that shows how you can prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

You could write:

```
find_address(X,Y):- 
          address(X,Y),
          atom_chars(Y,Y1),
          consecutive_member('1','0',Y1).

consecutive_member(X,Y,[X,Y|_]).
consecutive_member(X,Y,[H1,H2|T]):-
                    dif(H1,1),dif(H2,0),
                    consecutive_member(X,Y,T).
```

And query find_address(host1,X). which  succeeds only if there is an address for the host1 starting with '10':

```
?- find_address(host1,X).
X = '10.0.0.1' ;
false.
```

Comment: My intention was not to ignore a wrongly defined IP address, but to prevent the definition.

Comment: So how do you load the facts to the prolog database??

Comment: I have no preference. How should I do it? From what I have read till now, it seems to be usual to put them in a file with the extension `.pl`.

Comment: Yes but in this case if you put them manually you write them so you can't prevent the definition. If you load them dynamically with a predicate then you could check if they are right and if not just don't load them. So I can't understand why prevent them  in the first case (when creating a file.pl) since you write them???

Comment: For me there is no difference between writing them in file.pl or loading them from a source. In both cases the preconditions must be satisfied. For the moment it might be fine, that the precondition is in my head and I use this wisdom while I write the facts. But I think it is obvious what happens, when I forget to share this wisdom with a workmate, who needs to add some additional facts next week.